# Unable to connect to wifi on Nvidia Shield Portable

Tags: wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop, nvidia-shield, authentication

Recently picked up a used Nvidia Shield Portable to play around with. Digging it so far, but it refuses to connect to my Netgear Nighthawk MR60 Router and I'm not sure. Right now I have to tether off my phone just to use internet. I'm running stock android 5.1 with the latest updates

Best I can figure looking at the logcat logs from ADB is that it has something to do with this line.

```
W/wpa_supplicant(  583): wlan0: WPA: Failed to configure IGTK to the driver
I/wpa_supplicant(  583): wlan0: RSN: Failed to configure IGTK
```

I don't have my device rooted, so I don't know if I can disable PMF in the wpa_supplicant.conf. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the device?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried rebooting the device. No luck with that. I'm currently working on getting root access to see if I can fix it with that

Comment: I've now rooted the device. I went to the wpa_supplicant.conf files in both /system/etc/wifi/ and /data/misc/wifi/ and set pmf=0, however the file in data just resets pmf=1. I tried rebooting the device again after this but that changed nothing